# Protractor - How to use "or" in locators

Tags: css, protractor, automated-tests

What I want to achieve:
If the element is available then use it, if not then use another locator.

**Edit:**

My previous explanation was a bit poor so, let's start from begining. I have 2 cases:

1. When sale price is present.
2. When sale price is not present, only regular price is present.

**#1 Case Markup: When sale price is present.**

```
<td class="total-amount">
   <s>58.00</s> 
   <span>£30.50</span>
</td>
```

`span` - sale price.
`s` - regular price.

**#2 Case Markup: When there is no sale, only regular price is present**

```
<td class="total-amount">£78.00</td>
```

**Basket.js**

```
this.price = this.basket.element(by.css('.total-amount span, .total-amount'));
----
  totalAmount() {
    return this.getAttribute('attribute-name')
      .then(summaryprice => summaryprice.slice(1))
      .then(summaryprice => parseFloat(summaryprice));
  }
```

**Spec.js**

```
expect(delivery + price).toEqual(basket.totalAmount());
```

**#1 Case - Protractor Results: Failure**

```
Expected 30.5 to equal 58.
```

`30.5` - (it's delivery cost + price) and it's correct.
`58.0` - it's not correct, because the first condition is true so shouldn't it be `30.5`?

If I go for:

```
this.price = this.basket.element(by.css('.total-amount span'));
```

then there is no failure.

I want to write more flexible tests and cover both cases because prices change frequently.

Comment: Clarification needed, are both prices `span` or is one of the tags actually `s`?

Comment: Only "sale" price is in span, regular price is actually s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**
It seems your original locator is fine but your `totalAmount` function is not returning the correct value. If you do want to try an alternate approach to your locator to get price you could try this but the way you have should work.

```
let price = element(by.css('.total-amount span')).isDisplayed()
    .then(disp => {
        return element(by.css('.total-amount span'));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return element(by.css('.total-amount'));
    });
```

**Original Answer**

You are using 'OR' correctly but your locator is not structured correctly.

If we break down this locator `element(by.css('.total-amount span, .total-amount'));` we can see there are two conditions. If the first one is satisfied then it will be returned. If the first one is not satisfied then the second will be be returned if it is found.

However you will never get `30.50` returned as the second condition will return the `td` element itself . If you want to get the sale price if it is there but the `<s>` if it the sales price is not there then you the will need to run this line

```
element(by.css('.total-amount s, .total-amount span'))
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't get it.

.total-amount span is the first condition and even if this element is present then tests throw me element from the second condition.

Can you take a look at my first post? I added a little better explanation.

Comment: You can try the css selector `.total-amount span, .total-amount` in Chrome's DevTool and you will found the `td` is the first found element, not the `span`.  I think this is due to css selector priority strategy determined by css selector itself.

Comment: @Sadorus Based on your update it sounds like the issue is not with your locator but with the `totalAmount` function. What attribute are you searching for?

Comment: @DublinDev 
I'm looking for `textContent` attribute.

Comment: @Sadorus Is the `totalAmount` function pulling the expected value using the same locator? I'm not really clear on how it finds the value it needs